Confused between Multiple Random Variables and Likelihood Function
I am confused between the two at a very fundamental level. Following is the problem:
I take observations $\vec{x}$ and create a histogram $\mathbf{n} = (n_1,\ldots,n_N)$ out of it with $N$ bins. Number of elements in bin $i$ can be modelled as a Poisson random variable i.e. $n_i \sim Pois(\lambda_i)$ with parameter $\lambda_i = \mathbb{E}[n_i] = \mu s_i +b_i$ where $s_i$ and $b_i$ are the number of entries coming from distributions $f_s(x;\mathbf{\theta}_s)$ and $f_b(x;\mathbf{\theta}_b)$ respectively.
Now, when we write the Likelihood function $L(\mu,\theta_s,\theta_b|n_1,\ldots,n_N)$ of this histogram as:
$$
\begin{align*}
  L(\mu,\theta_s,\theta_b;\vec{n}) &= f(n_1|\lambda_1) \cdots f(n_N|\lambda_N) \\
&= \prod_{i=1}^{N} f(n_i|\lambda_i)\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^{N} \frac{\lambda_i^{n_i}}{n_i!}e^{-\lambda_i} \\
&= \prod_{i=1}^{N} \frac{(\mu s_i + b_i)^{n_i}}{n_i!}e^{-(\mu s_i + b_i)}
\end{align*}
$$
Does this mean that my data is $N$-dimensional (which most probably is not but I still want to ask) or is it the case that I am calculating likelihood of $N$ i.i.d samples?

Because $N$ is fixed, no bin can contain  more than $N$ values, whence a Poisson distribution is incorrect.  It could approximately work, but why not use the correct multinomial probability?

@whuber Because $p_i$ (probability of an entry falling into bin $i$) is small whereas $M$ is large. So, can we not somehow apply Poisson Limit Theorem here? The entries to each bin $i$ can be only of two types - coming from $f_s$ or $f_b$ with probabilities adding to 1. So, applying Poisson Limit Theorem to each bin, do we not get the same likelihood as above?

As I wrote, you can sometimes use this approximation.  But why?  It's more complicated to analyze in many respects than the fully correct multinomial likelihood.

Because M is large and it would help in computation. The data comes in two flavours - s and b. We know that number of b >> number of s. So, can we also somehow use the combination of both? Multinomial for s (which is low) and Poisson for b (which is high)?

It's not at all apparent how the computation would be assisted by using a Poisson likelihood.  The multinomial is no problem at all (one uses the log Gamma function, of course, to compute a log likelihood).

I do not believe you intend to create a histogram out of an observation $x$, but rather you require a sample, $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_M$ (reserve $N$ for your histogram treatment). But for the sake of discussion you can set $M=1$.
Your sample space indeed is $M$ dimensional, such as $\mathbb{R}^M$ or some subset. You can define the histogram as a statistic defined on $\mathbb{N}^N$, so it is N dimensional. Even with $M=1$, the permutation of possible values for $\vec{n}$ are $[1,0,\ldots, 0], [0,1,\ldots,0], \ldots, [0,0,\ldots, 1]$. forming a basis for $\mathbb{N}^N$.
That said, I do not believe your likelihood is well defined! The distribution of $n_i$ is clearly not Poisson! Since the histogram is a statistic, you need to feed the initial sample conditions into specifying the model. So first any $n_i$ is bounded by $M$, and second the $n_i$ are not mutually independent. I believe the correct probability model for the histogram is hypergeometric with probabilities defined by the DF for the $x_i$ integrated over the binning interval.

I intended to write $\vec{x}$ instead of $x$. You're right, number of observations can of course not be 1.

About the distribution of $n_i$, I am following this paper (Page 4). Why would $n_i$ be not Poisson distributed? The bins are being filled independently of each other and at a constant rate.

@Siddhartha do you not agree that a bin is bounded by the total sample size as I stated?

So you want to say a multinomial distribution should be used because we have a finite number of sample which affects the 'independence' condition that we have assumed for $n_i$? What if M is large? And how large it should be before we can model $n_i$ as Poisson?

@Sid There are approximations, but one would expect an accurate expression of the likelihood before defaulting to them.

Wait, if we drop the Poisson approximation part, wouldn't it be multinomial distribution instead of hypergeometric ($M$ is large)? If $\vec{x} = (x_1,\ldots, x_M)$ is our data, we can be distribute into $N$ bins and therefore, the distribution should be multinomial such that $(n_1,\ldots, n_N) \sim \text{Multinomial}(M, N, \vec{p})$ where $\vec{p}=(p_1,\ldots,p_N)$ and $p_i$ is the probability of data landing up in bin $i$.

@Sid You induce a random process by creating the bins for the histogram. There are approaches that result in a hypergeometric conditional process, and approaches that result in a multinomial conditional process as far as counts in the bins.

Can you recommend me some books/articles where I can read specifically about this more?
